# Table does not reload upon clicking element in another table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to refresh the second table upon clicking an element of the first table. The first table loads but the second one does not load its data when I click an element of the first table.

First table:

```
<div id="master-table" ng-controller="purchaseInvoiceController">
<table dir="rtl" width="500" border="2" style="background:#ddd;
      summary="purpose/structure for speech output">

  <colgroup width="33%" />
  <colgroup id="colgroup" class="colgroup" align="center"
      valign="middle" title="title" width="33%"
      span="2" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Invoice No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="addProduct" id="addProduct" ng-model="purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceId"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="addProduct" id="addProduct" ng-model="purchaseInvoice.amount"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="addProduct" id="addProduct" ng-model="purchaseInvoice.dateInvoiced"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="table-element" ng-repeat="purchaseInvoice in purchaseInvoices" ng-click="getLines(purchaseInvoice)">
      <td>{{purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceId}}</td>
      <td>{{purchaseInvoice.amount}}</td>
      <td>{{purchaseInvoice.dateInvoiced}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Second Table body:

```
<tbody>
        <tr id="table-element" ng-repeat="purchaseInvoiceLine in purchaseInvoiceLines">
          <td>{{purchaseInvoiceLine.purchaseInvoiceId}}</td>
          <td>{{purchaseInvoiceLine.purchaseInvoiceLineId}}</td>
</tbody>
```

The getLines() function runs when I click an element of the first table and the data is loaded in the JavaScript message I'm using for testing. However, the second table does not load its data upon clicking the master element. The AngularJS module is as follows:

```
angular.module('pu', []).controller('purchaseInvoiceController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  var createURL = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/create";
  var updateURL = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/update";
  var allPurchaseInvoices = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices";
  var lines = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/1/lines";

  $scope.purchaseInvoice = {};
  $scope.purchaseInvoiceLine = {};
  $scope.editBtn = false;

  $http.get(allPurchaseInvoices).then(function(response) {
    $scope.purchaseInvoices = response.data;
  });

  $scope.getLines = function(purchaseInvoice) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/' + purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceId + '/lines').then(function(json){
      $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines = json.data;
      alert('done! ' + $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines[0].lineAmount);
    });
  }

}]);
```

Comment: Just I am wondering, do you have the second table inside the 'purchaseInvoiceController'?

Comment: No, I only have functions that manipulate purchase orders using REST services like createPurchaseInvoice, editPurchaseInvoice and so on...

Comment: I have updated my answer below regarding the second controller and check the same. Unless you post the full code, it's very hard to give you the right answer and we need to make few assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good and I can't find any issues.

The one I want you to look at is whether your second table exists inside the following div which has the ng-controller,

```
<div id="master-table" ng-controller="purchaseInvoiceController">
```

Since, I can see the div id as "master-table", I suspect your second table may be outside the controller and in this case, it won't get refreshed.

If this is the case, then move the second table inside the above div and give a try.

If this is not the case, then post the entire html to look at further.

Also, if you declared your second controller as below then the module will be reinitialized and you will loose your first controller methods.

```
angular.module('pu', []).controller
```

If you need to use two or more controllers inside the same page then declare the module first with the second argument then use the same to all the controllers without a second parameter as below.

```
var app = angular.module('pu', []);
// without second parameter 
angular.module('pu').controller
```

Comment: Can you post the entire div?

Comment: Also, if you had any second controller used inside the same page then, please post the controller code

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="master-table" ng-controller="purchaseInvoiceController">
                <table dir="rtl" width="500" border="2" style="background:#ddd;
                      summary="purpose/structure for speech output">

                  <colgroup width="33%" />
                  <colgroup id="colgroup" class="colgroup" align="center"
                      valign="middle" title="title" width="33%"
                      span="2" />
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Invoice No</th>
                      <th scope="col">Invoice Line No.</th>
                      <th scope="col">Date invoiced</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
        <tr id="table-element" ng-repeat="purchaseInvoiceLine in purchaseInvoiceLines">
          <td>{{purchaseInvoiceLine.purchaseInvoiceId}}</td>
          <td>{{purchaseInvoiceLine.purchaseInvoiceLineId}}</td>
</tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
```

This is the div of the second table. I think the div should also be inside the controller...

Comment: It seems you have two divs with the same controller two times. What will happen in this case is, angular will creat two controller instances. Think controller like a class or object and you will get two different instances.

Comment: Hence updating the model inside the first instance won't modify the model inside the second instance where your second controller is there. So the 'purchaseInvoiceLines' is always empty in the second instance as it gets populated in the first instance

Comment: As I said in my answer above, it should be one div with one instance of controller

Comment: If you need two separate divs, then create one master div, assign the ng-controller to it, then place the two divs inside the master div without ng-controller. If you can't do this, then simply remove the ng-controller from the two divs and move it to the body tag or any common parent to these two divs.

Comment: The high level idea is "ng-controller="purchaseInvoiceController">" should be in one place to the parent of both divs

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole controller:

```
    angular.module('pu', []).controller('purchaseInvoiceController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  var createURL = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/create";
  var updateURL = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/update";
  var allPurchaseInvoices = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices";
  var lines = "http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/1/lines";

  $scope.purchaseInvoice = {};
  $scope.purchaseInvoiceLine = {};
  $scope.editBtn = false;

  $http.get(allPurchaseInvoices).then(function(response) {
    $scope.purchaseInvoices = response.data;
  });

  /*$http.get(lines).then(function(response) {
    $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines = response.data;
  });*/


  $scope.getLines = function(purchaseInvoice) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/' + purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceId + '/lines').then(function(json){
      $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines = json.data;
      alert('done! ' + $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines[0].lineAmount);
    });
  }

  /*$scope.getLines = funtion(purchaseInvoice) {
    $scope.get('http://localhost:8080/webapi/purchaseInvoices/' + purchaseInvoice.purchaseInvoiceId + '/lines').then(function(response) {
      $scope.purchaseInvoiceLines = response.data;
    });
  }*/

  $scope.createPurchaseInvoice = function() {
    $http.post(createURL, $scope.purchaseInvoice).success(function(response) {
      $http.get(allPurchaseInvoices).then(function(response) {
        $scope.purchaseInvoices = response.data;
        alert('Purchase Invoice has been created!');
      });
    });
  }

  $scope.editPurchaseInvoice = function(purchaseInvoice) {
    $scope.purchaseInvoice = purchaseInvoice;
  }

  $scope.update = function() {
    $http.put(updateURL, $scope.purchaseInvoice).success(function(response) {
      $http.get(allPurchaseInvoices).then(function(response) {
        $scope.purchaseInvoices = response.data;
        alert('Purchase Invoice has been updated!');
      });
    });
  }

  $scope.delete = function(purchaseInvoiceId) {
    var result = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (result === true) {
      $http.delete(allPurchaseInvoices + '/' + purchaseInvoiceId).success(function(response) {
        $http.get(allPurchaseInvoices).then(function(response) {
          $scope.purchaseInvoices = response.data;
          alert('Purchase Invoice Deleted!');
        });
      });
    }
  }

}]);
```